# Why does DATEDIFF treat 23:59.59.999 as the next day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following:

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime = '2017-12-01 23:59:59.998'
DECLARE @date2 datetime = '2017-12-11 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2)
```

I get 10 as expected since it only compares the day part

However, if I add one millisecond:

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime = '2017-12-01 23:59:59.999'
DECLARE @date2 datetime = '2017-12-11 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @date1, @date2)
```

I get 9. It seems like SQL Server is rounding 23:59.59.999 to 24:00.00.000 and thus the next day but won't round up anything else. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: hint: see what `SELECT @date1` returns

Comment: Just checked the conversion to DATE and 'CONVERT(date, @date1)' returns 2017-12-01 when the millisecond part is set to .999 but not .998

Comment: @user3220670 Why don't you use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`

Comment: @Lamak, thanks, looks like the datetime value is rounded to.000, .003, or .007 as per this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision

Comment: @Sami, the date I'm given is in `datetime` and converting it to `datetime2` wouldn't make sense

Comment: I don't think I say cast it before, Use <> cast.

Comment: @Sami, not sure I understand. I wasn't able to find anything about <> cast and using `CAST()` in the function I'm writing results in an error

Comment: Basically, you won't be able to compare these two as a datetime datatype. That SQL datatype doesn't have enough precision, and results in the number being rounded up. You would see the same behavior if you were trying to compare x.006 to x.007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS SQL Uses 
4 bytes to store the days past Jan 1, 1900.
4 bytes to store the clock ticks past midnight. ( a tick is 3.3miliseconds)

What you are seeing is overflow. Since the number can not be represented by the 4 bytes, it will use the 5th byte thus incrementing the day by 1.

> SQL Server stores the second integer for the time as the number of
>   clock ticks after midnight. A second contains 300 ticks, so a tick
>   equals 3.3 milliseconds (ms). You can see the values for days and
>   clock ticks by converting a datetime value to a binary(8) value and
>   using the substring function to extract each set of 4 bytes. The code
>   in Figure 3 then converts each set of 4 bytes into an integer.

Source: http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery

Comment: . . Although accurate, you should explain how this affects what the OP is seeing.

Comment: Technically, it increments the .xx9 seconds by 1, which trickles up to rounding to the next day. This is one of the reasons why it's better to ultimately use `datetime2` datatypes if you have the option. There's deeper precision.